# Meteor - sergeyt:typeahead - Not injecting when inside an {{#each}}

Tags: meteor, typeahead.js

I have several instances of sergeyt:typeahead working in my webapp. However today I am building a table out of data from query. One of the columns needs to allow for possibly selecting from a collection or if the user wants to enter their own value.

This has worked for me in other parts. Now it appears that when using an {{#each}} statement in the html and when the typeahead is inside the {{#each}} that it does not receive the injecting.

I believe this may be due to the fact that inject is typically done on the rendered which is run before the {{#each}} has run and created the dom elements. And if that is the case how would I go about then placing the inject on these newly generated elements?

Comment: You wouldn't want one typeahead per row would you? Don't you want the typeahead to be tied to the table header and therefore outside the `{{#each}}`?

Comment: I am,actually looking to have multiple typeaheads per row.

Comment: What I am looking to do is that each row of the table represents a stop in a route. Each stop needs to  have the ability to dispatch it to someone either already in the person collection or a user typed in one. This need to happen in line in the table row. The problem lies in that I don't know ahead of time how many rows a job will have.  Thus having to use the #each to produce the rows that contain the typeahead. But the #each is run after the template is rendered so using the inject command is not working on all the elements in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a sub template for each stop:

```
<template name='myApp'>
  {{#each stops}}
    {{> stop}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="stop">
  <input class="form-control typeahead" ...>
</template>
```

This way you can call `typeahead.inject` on each instance after it is rendered.

```
Template.stop.onRendered(function() {
  Meteor.typeahead.inject();
});
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I will try that tomorrow and let you know. Thank you.